# Simple IIS url rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

I am trying to hide a subdirectory where I installed a framework. While this works like a charm in .htaccess, I am getting stuck with IIS rules. Basically I want to go from 
http://www.mysite.com/CI/client-tracking to
http://www.mysite.com/client-tracking

I am using this rule

```
<rule name="Redirect to Codeigniter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^client-tracking$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/CI/client-tracking"  />
</rule>
```

LE: I am not in need of a redirect, I need to rewrite the URL and eliminate the \CI directory from it, so the user and search engines see a nice link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the leading "/" on the re-written url

```
<rule name="Redirect to Codeigniter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^client-tracking$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="CI/client-tracking"  />
</rule>
```